# not optimum mode recommended mode 1920x1080

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, display

I recently got a new graphics card(NVIDIA GTX 1080) and replaced my old one(NVIDIA GTX 970). I booted my desktop (Asus G10AJ) and I get a screen like this:

[image]

I was able to get to the grub menu screen, and I select ubuntu. Then right after I see the Ubuntu splash screen it gives me that screen.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Or do I need to purchase a new monitor.

Comment: Have you tried lowering the resolution via the command line to the one recommended by your screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screen is telling you that the resolution your computer is trying to use is outside the range that this monitor supports.

You'll need to boot your computer into VGA mode, framebuffer mode, or whatever the lack of a video driver is called in Linux these days.  Once you're in then you'll need to probably reinstall the nVidia drivers.

Comment: I couldn't get the VGA mode to work, but i used recovery mode and reinstalled the driver. Thanks!